# Is there a way to troubleshoot why Xdebug not stopping at breakpoints in VSCode?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug, laragon, xdebug-3

I have been working on why Xdebug is not stopping at breakpoints for days. I have read and tried dozens of solutions on StackOverflow. None of them have worked. **Is there a method to troubleshoot why the configuration is not working?**. Any help would be greatly appreciated since I have been working on this problem for days.

My setup:

I am using Windows 10, which is loaded on drive C.  On my `F:` drive, I have Laragon (local server), which contains my (PHP v7.2.19) file. My VSCode is also on the F: drive. VSCode uses the extension PHP Debug by Felix Becker.

VSCode Launch.json:

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Listen for XDebug",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",            
        "port": 9000, 
    },
    {
        "name": "Launch currently open script",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
        "port": 9000
    }
]
```

I have followed the Xdebug wizard and downloaded & installed everything as instructed. Below is my php.ini file in my Laragon installation.

php.ini

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension = "F:\Laragon\bin\php\php-7.2.19-Win32-VC15-x64\ext\php_xdebug-3.0.0-7.2-vc15-x86_64.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
```

The extension seems to be loaded:

```
DEBUG     Checking PHPLS_ALLOW_XDEBUG
DEBUG     The xdebug extension is loaded (3.0.0)
DEBUG     Process restarting (PHPLS_ALLOW_XDEBUG=internal|3.0.0|0|*|*)
DEBUG     Running f:\laragon\bin\php\php-7.2.19-Win32-VC15-x64\php.exe -n -c C:\Users\Bill\AppData\Local\Temp\CA11.tmp c:\Users\Bill\.vscode\extensions\felixfbecker.php-intellisense-2.3.14\vendor\felixfbecker\language-server\bin\php-language-server.php --tcp=127.0.0.1:13121 --memory-limit=4095M

DEBUG     Checking PHPLS_ALLOW_XDEBUG
WARNING   Restarted (130 ms). The xdebug extension is loaded (3.0.0)
```

Is there a way or method to troubleshoot my setup?

Comment: 1) Xdebug 3 (that you have) uses DIFFERENT config parameters than Xdebug v2 (that you are trying to use in your php.ini). Please check the Upgrade docs for Xdebug 3 and configure using the right parameters: https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide

Comment: 2) You can always check current Xdebug config by capturing `phpinfo()` output in a same way you are trying to debug (web page or CLI). Just look at the dedicated section for Xdebug extension. 3) After you have configured it, it all looks good but still does not work: enable and check Xdebug log -- it will tell if it tries to connect to VSCode or not, what the response is etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you LazyOne for directing me to the answer in the comments.  The problem was, I was using XDebug 2 parameters when I should have been using XDebug 3.   Thank you also WebEXP0528 for your posting of a suggested answer.  However, the reference to the website really helped me understand why I was changing the php.ini file. The webpage reference xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide gave a lot of information that helped me troubleshoot the problem.

Old:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension = "F:\Laragon\bin\php\php-7.2.19-Win32-VC15-x64\ext\php_xdebug-3.0.0-7.2-vc15-x86_64.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
```

New php.ini based on xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension = "F:\Laragon\bin\php\php-7.2.19-Win32-VC15-x64\ext\php_xdebug-3.0.0-7.2-vc15-x86_64.dll"
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
xdebug.discover_client_host = 1
```

Comment: Thank you !!!! I have been struggling with this for ages now...

Answer (score 0):

In php.ini

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension = "F:\Laragon\bin\php\php-7.2.19-Win32-VC15-x64\ext\php_xdebug-3.0.0-7.2-vc15-x86_64.dll"
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.idekey=VSCODE
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.client_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.client_port=9001
```

Answer (score 0):

Me I use laravel 2.2.2 some version don't work with x debug and i use following line code on my php ini file
zend_extension = php_xdebug-2.9.8-7.1-vc14.dll and
`[XDebug] xdebug.remote_enable = 1 xdebug.remote_autostart = 1`